# RestAssured - Testing Restful API using Selenium and Test NG - when run throws connection timeout error

Tags: selenium, testng, rest-assured

I am testing a Weather Rest API using Restassured and TestNG framework. Following is the code: 
I made sure I have all the dependencies covered in pom.xml file
This is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.addListener(Lorg/testng/ISuiteListener;)V
   at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:122)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;


public class RestApi_Weather_GET {      

   @Test
   void GetWeatherDetails(){          

      //specify the base uri
     RestAssured.baseURI = "http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city/";

     //Request object is being created
     RequestSpecification ahttprequest = RestAssured.given();           

     //Response object
     Response aresponse = ahttprequest.request(Method.GET, "Alameda");            

    //print response in console
    String aresponseBody = aresponse.getBody().asString();            

     System.out.println("Response body is : "+aresponseBody);

   }
 }
```

Comment: What has this to do with [tag:selenium]?

Comment: This project is part of Selenium-Java. RestAssured is a framework to test restful api's

Comment: What version of TestNG are you using and what tool are you using to run the tests? Eclipse TestNG plugin maybe?

Comment: You might be having two different versions of TestNG in your project. Try by removing one of the version